# How to add an image in display.newCircle() in corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to change the color of a circle with a custom image. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Try

```
-- Create a vector rectangle
local circle = display.newCircle( 200, 200, 300 )

-- Set the fill (paint) to use the bitmap image
local paint = {
    type = "image",
    filename = "texture1.png"
}

-- Fill the circle
circle.fill = paint
```

More information you can find in [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/path.html#fillstroke).